# Horizontal ScrollView not fit its sub ImageViews?

Tags: ios, swift, horizontalscrollview, autoscroll

I want horizontal scrollview with image view but image is not fitting with the scroll. i am doing this code but not getting the right thing 
Here is my code

```
@IBOutlet weak var upperScroll: UIScrollView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        var logoImage: [UIImage] = [
            UIImage(named: "slider.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "slider.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "slider.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "slider.png")!,
        ]

        upperScroll.isScrollEnabled = true
        let scrollWidth: Int = Int(self.view.frame.width)
        upperScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(scrollWidth), height:(self.upperScroll.frame.height))
        upperScroll.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 51, width: upperScroll.frame.size.width, height: self.upperScroll.frame.height)
        upperScroll.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        var xOffset: Int = 0
        for index in 0..<logoImage.count {
            let img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(xOffset), y: 0, width: upperScroll.frame.size.width, height: self.upperScroll.frame.height))
            img.image = logoImage[index]
            upperScroll.addSubview(img)
            xOffset += 100
        }
        view.addSubview(upperScroll)
        upperScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat((scrollWidth + xOffset)), height: 110)

    }
```

[image: i am getting this] but i want this [image: type]

Can anyone please help me? Thanks

Comment: you are adding 4 times the same picture, that's strange isn't it ?

Comment: You should be using `UICollectionView` for this kind of feature.

Comment: @GuyKogus i have tried collection view but i am not getting the full width image view

Comment: @CZ54 firstly i am testing , when the page will show what i want then i will use the image from the webservice

Comment: As @GuyKogus said, use `collectionView` instead of scrollview. It will be efficient and time-saving. You have to give the `itemSize` width to be same as `collectionView`'s width.

Comment: @BadhanGanesh ok i will try collectionview as what you have wrote the property of item size, if some error occurs then i will write here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove your **appdelegate** code and add my  fuction 
also set scrollview constraint like leading,trailing,top,bottom Zero

```
  func scrollImage() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = true
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
            var logoImage: [UIImage] = [
            UIImage(named: "slider.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "slider.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "slider.png")!,
            UIImage(named: "slider.png")!]

            upperScroll.isPagingEnabled = true

            upperScroll.isScrollEnabled = true

            let scrollWidth: Int = Int(self.view.frame.width)
,
            upperScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat(scrollWidth), height:(self.upperScroll.frame.height))
            print(upperScroll.frame.size.width)
            upperScroll.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
            for index in 0..<logoImage.count {
                let xPosition = self.view.frame.width * CGFloat(index)
                upperScroll.layoutIfNeeded()
                let img = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(xPosition), y: 0, width: upperScroll.frame.size.width, height: self.upperScroll.frame.height))
                img.layoutIfNeeded()
                img.image = logoImage[index]
                upperScroll.addSubview(img)
            }
            view.addSubview(upperScroll)
            upperScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat((scrollWidth) * logoImage.count), height: self.upperScroll.frame.height)

        }
```

I hope it's save your time and working great

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement, the `xOffset += 100` should be changed to `xOffset += scrollWidth`. And contents size set to:

```
upperScroll.contentSize = CGSize(width: CGFloat((scrollWidth * logoImage.count)), height: 110)
```

And remember to enable the pagination for scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need two outlet for scroll view and PageControl,

```
 var contentWidth:CGFloat = 0.0

// MARK: - Welcome screen with scroll view use page controll

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    scrollView.delegate = self
    let myImages = ["intro1_1.png", "intro2_2.png", "intro3_3.png"] // images which loaded in assets
    let imageWidth:CGFloat = view.frame.width
    let imageHeight:CGFloat = view.frame.height
    var xPosition:CGFloat = 0 //setup your position
    var scrollViewSize:CGFloat=0 //setup your position

    for image in myImages {
        let myImage:UIImage = UIImage(named: image)!
        let myImageView:UIImageView = UIImageView()
        myImageView.image = myImage
        myImageView.frame.size.width = imageWidth
        myImageView.frame.size.height = imageHeight
        myImageView.frame.origin.x = xPosition
        myImageView.frame.origin.y = 0
        scrollView.addSubview(myImageView)
        xPosition += imageWidth
        scrollViewSize += imageWidth
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollViewSize, height: imageHeight)
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width * 3, height: view.frame.height) //here you setup how many pages in scroll will

}

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let pageWidth:CGFloat = scrollView.frame.width
    let currentPage:CGFloat = floor((scrollView.contentOffset.x-pageWidth / 2)/pageWidth)+1
    self.pageControll.currentPage = Int(currentPage)
}
```

hope, i help u